# Why this script doesn't print output like xxd

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a hexdump with a help of a tutorial but I need it doesnt display exactly like xxd output. Please tell me what I need to change.

```
import sys
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("file", help="Input File")
args = parser.parse_args()

try:
 with open (args.file, 'rb') as infile:
  with open (args.file+".dump", 'w') as outfile:        #opening a with .dump extension to save the output
        offset = 0
        while True:
            line = infile.read(16)          #reading the input file as 16 byte
            if len(line) == 0:
                break
            text = str(line)
            output ="{:08x}".format(offset)+ ":"    #generating the offset with 8 zeores in hex format "x"
            output+=" ".join([f"{a:02X}" for a in line[:8]])
            output+="  "                        #space between 8 hex byte
            output+=" ".join([f"{a:02x}" for a in line[8:]])
            output+="    " + text

            print (output)
            outfile.write(output + '\n')        #writing the output to .dump file
            offset += 16





except:
print ("Input File not found!!")        #exception if input file is not present
```

```
This is the output I needed

00000000: 4469 6c73 6861 6e20 4c61 6b73 6869 7468  Dilshan Lakshith
00000010: 6120 0a4e 6962 6d0a                      a .Nibm.



This is the output I get from my script I need this to be in four numbers but not two's

00000000:44 69 6C 73 68 61 6E 20  4c 61 6b 73 68 69 74 68    b'Dilshan Lakshith'
00000010:61 20 0A 4E 69 62 6D 0A                             b'a \nNibm\n'
```

Comment: What does it output and what do you expect it to output?

Comment: It input a file from command line arguments and I need to output a hexdump exactly as xxd output, I uploaded a image for your preference

Comment: Please edit your question with an example of what you're giving in, and an example of what you would expect out, and what you're getting out for given input.

Comment: Don't attach an image. That one isn't even readable. Copy and past and edit your question instead.

Comment: Check this https://gist.github.com/sbz/1080258

Comment: @AjayTomGeorge That code print like mine. I need the output to be in four's this is for a assignment in my college